# SSIS error - "the buffer manager cannot extend the file" due to "insufficient disk space"

Tags: ssis, buffer, etl, diskspace

I have an SSIS data flow designed to cleanse the data from one table and put it in another table:

[image]

While running the package, I received the following error:

> Error: The buffer manager cannot extend the file
>   "C:\Users\VSA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\DTS{7F58BAB1-436A-49E4-877A-BFC412BF1F42}.tmp"
>   to length 10469604 bytes.  There was insufficient disk space.

The log shows the following: 
[image]

The disk shows over 100 GB of free space.  Are there any SSIS settings that I need to change?

Comment: Is the disk full while running the package?

Comment: No,I have over 100 GB of space in the Disk

Comment: Try to change the `BufferTempStoragePath` of the `Sort` task to a different location. A location which you are 100% that the account running the package has the correct permissions on to extend the file.

Comment: it looks like you could use Union instead of merge and save the time-consuming sorts, do you use merge for any particular reason?